# Invalid token when resetting passoword in production stage

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-3

When I try to reset my password after clicking link (accepted via email) for redirectin me to Reset Password Page,sometimes it shows that Token is invalid, but when I click to that link again a couple of times it shows that Token is valid. This happened only in Production stage because in Test stage token is always valid.
What can cause this problem and how could be fixed?

I used to generate the token by this line of code:

```
var token = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);
```

Comment: Have you implemented a persistent store for the data protection API? And if you run multiple instances of the same application (i.e. horizontally scaled), does each one access the same store?

Comment: No. How can I do it if it's useful to solve this problem ?

Comment: I'd start with the official docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/introduction?view=aspnetcore-6.0) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/using-data-protection?view=aspnetcore-6.0). In my case, our API pods are allowed to scale out horizontally to as many as 10 instances running concurrently, so a separate key store is required to ensure that as keys are generated, they are accessible from all instances. If you only have one server instance, then you only need to persist the keys between restarts.

Comment: All implementations are done but in production stage we also use two servers, and I think that is the reason why token sometimes is valid and sometimes invalid.

Comment: If the two servers aren't using the same key store then you will have this problem. If server A generates a key and encrypts some data with it, then you try and decrypt that data with server B, then it will fail because you don't have the key. You need to use or implement a custom key store that both servers can access simultaneously. When server A generates a key, it will be saved in the key store. When server B needs it, it can be retrieved from the key store.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/implementation/key-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar Thanks a lot. I did all implementations in Entity Framework Core and it's working perfectly.